# Jade и PHP

Tags: jade, php

Как мне вставить в Jade код навроде:

```
<?php test(); ?>
```

чтобы он не испортился компилятором Jade ?

Comment: а, собственно, зачем?

Comment: Дак я хочу вкрапления ПХПшные, из базы дергать чего-нибудь и т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Вижу дату, скорее всего вы уже нашли ответ, но все же оставлю здесь для тех, кто зайдет сюда через поиск. Вдруг пригодится.
Если это просто отдельная строка php кода, то можно просто писать так:
`title <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>`
Если это параметр, который надо передать в функцию jade, то надо писать так:
`meta(charset!="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>")`
здесь знак "!" отключает экранирование php включений в jade.
Надеюсь понятно объяснил :)

Answer (score 0):

Можете просто такой комбинацией:

```
| <?php test(); ?>
```

Или же используйте Jade-PHP.